# Objects not appearing in Blender in 3d viewport

Tags: rendering, 3d-view

The local view port has a can I made earlier, but when I come to global 3d view everything disappears please see the second 3d viewport its global perspective ,why is this happening as you can see in ouliner the objects are visible why is this happening ? I have attached image and file itself

[image]

https://imgur.com/QCO58G1

https://www.mediafire.com/?9crrwp8hv3do73d

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are on the wrong layer as your objects are in layer one, just press <kbd>1</kbd> with the mouse over the 3d view.

Comment: more info on layers: https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/layers.html?highlight=layers

Answer (score 0):

Easy mistake to fix you're on the wrong layer.  Just go ahead and click *1* while your cursor is in the 3D viewport to make everything appear.